# If $X$ is a topological space with the cofinite topology. I want to know when $X$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a topological space with the cofinite topology. I want to know when $X$ is connected.

Now I know that If $X$ is infinite then it is connected.

But I don't know how to have a complete answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a finite set, the cofinite topology and the discrete topology are the same thing, because all sets have finite complement.

Answer (score 0):

If $X=A\cup B$, with $A$ and $B$ open, disjoint and not empty, then $B=X\setminus A$ is closed and proper, hence finite; similarly for $A$. Hence…

Conversely…

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a finite set then every subset of $X$ is co-finite in $X $, so every subset of $X$ is open.  If $p\in X$ but $\{p\}\ne X$ then $\{p\}$ and $X$ \ $\{p\}$ are disjoint and non-empty and their union is $X.$ So $X$ is disconnected unless $X$ has just one member, or is the empty set.